# Creating a new group

Tags: odoo

I've made a custom module for the warehouse and now I want this module to be available to a new group.

This new group needs to inherit from the stock manager, so it has to have all the rights the stock manager has + access to this new module.

In my xml I defined:

```
    <record id="group_stock_manager_editor" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Manager Editor</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_warehouse_management"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_stock_manager')), (4, ref('account.group_account_user'))]"/>
        <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
    </record>
```

But this doesn't seem to work, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, the problem was that I wanted to inherit the rights from the `group_stock_manager` from a custom module, so instead of `group_stock_manager` it had to be `stock.group_stock_manager`